# SQLAlchemy Delete All Dependencies and Add All Dependencies

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `Configuration`. `Configuration` has multiple fields that are expressed as lists with each table using a `ForeignKey` to `Configuration`.

So an example of one of these tables is `Users` with a foreign key to `Configuration` and another column as `username`.

I have a form that is sent to update each of the `Configuration` as in theory should update each of the dependent tables with relevant information.

For example, I might currently have

```
Configuration
with Users: [Bob, John]
```

and the form provides

```
Configuration
with Users: [Jan]
```

Now, I only want one row for `Configuration`, and one row in `Users` with `Jan`.

Instead, `Bob` and `John` are deleted. How can I do this in one transaction so that the user querying the database either sees the new config or the old config.

I am currently doing something like:

```
clear_dependents(id)
db.session.commit()
add_dependents(id, fields)
db.session.commit()
```

However, since I commit after clearing dependent tables, a querying application could in theory see an empty configuration. How do I avoid this and rollback to the old config if updating the new table fails?

I have tried `db.session.flush()` but this does not work if the new configuration from the form includes older configuration values (duplicate error). Example of the failure would be using:

`with Users: [Jan, Bob] as Bob has not been deleted on an dependent table yet`